# Thunderbird - messages grouped by conversation - tree is open

Tags: thunderbird

I have the mails in all my folders grouped by conversation. After the latest Update to Thunderbird 115.3.1, all these groups are automatically "open" when I start Thunderbird (meaning that I see the tree with all the messages instead of only one line for all messages and being able to open them). This was different before the update.

How can I change that back?

Comment: This should probably better be asked in the Thunderbird forums.

Comment: 1. Revert to an older T'bird: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1072409 2. Register that behavior as a bug: https://developer.thunderbird.net/thunderbird-development/fixing-a-bug

Comment: I downgraded to an older version but the problem is still there (btw only in the Inbox folder - in all other folders the trees are closed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I went into View > Threads > Collapse all Threads.
Now they remain collapsed when I open Thunderbird or switch folder (type of action which would re-expand the tree systematically before).